# Salesforce marketing cloud email result table

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are integrating marketing cloud data into our BI system and would need to know the table where all the individual email results are stored on the salesforce marketing cloud platform. This is the list data tables marketing cloud has:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/account.htm

Has anybody been able to find the table that contains all the indivual email results? This table should contain indivual email sends for each recipient (email address).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not the above Account object, but look at [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5). Especially:

- Send
- Open
- Click

These Data Views can be extracted and provided to the BI systems, using Automation Studio and [Data Extract Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5).

Comment: we are using a direct connector (SSIS Data Flow Components for Salesforce Marketing Cloud) and we have access to the data. We would need to know though how to get the raw email send data. Based on the above, these are likely then in the following https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sentevent.htm, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/openevent.htm,https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/clickevent.htm